Business Hour Time zone should we have to change in every day light savings time
If timezone is changed in "Company Information" for a Salesforce Org (Org-Wide Time zone) in a particular Day Light Savings Time(Suppose November 3, 2024), then a particular Business Hour Time zone will be changed or not?, Or we have to manually change the business hour time zone?
Note: Business Hour Time zone is the same as Org-Wide time zone.

If you change timezone in "company information", It does not automatically update the time zone for Business Hours, even if they are initially set to the same timezone. If you change the Org-Wide Timezone, you will need to manually update the Business Hours timezone to match the new setting if desired.
Resoan behind this Business Hours are often used in conjunction with other features like escalation rules and service level agreements, which may rely on consistent timezone settings. That's why Salesforce allows for Business Hours to be managed independently to ensure that any changes are intentional and do not inadvertently affect other processes.
Change default time zones for Users and the organization.
